# Using Gravity for Infinite energy?

Tags: gravity, energy, energy-conservation

Can gravity be used as an infinite energy source? What if you throw objects down, say a hill, and had a panel on the bottom that would use the force of the fall and convert it to energy? Would this violate the law of conservation of energy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gravity could be used as an energy source in the way you describe, but like all other energy sources, it comes at a cost. In order to roll something down a hill you have to get it to the top of the hill first, and moving something to the top of a hill requires energy. Of course, you could just roll things down the hill that are already at the tops of hills (because of some natural process), but that practice is not sustainable ( and not, I would guess, efficient). This is basically like burning fossil fuels: we are burning chemicals which are naturally at the top of the chemical energy hill and moving them to tower energy states, and using the results to run our cars and heat our homes.

Using gravity to generate usable energy does not violate conservation of energy because it is simply the conversion of potential energy (at the top of the hill) to kinetic energy (at the bottom) to electrical energy, or whatever other kind of energy you panel delivers.

Answer (score 1):

> what if you through objects down, sya a hill, and had a panel on the bottom that would use the force of the fall and convert it to energy? would this violate the law of conservation of energy?

**No, this setup would not violate the law of conservation of energy.**

*But* it is also not a source of *infinite* energy. Because at some point the object reaches the bottom of the hill and no more energy can be converted in this way. Our sooner or later you run out of objects to throw down the hill.

The bottom line is that to get a constant supply of energy, you must bring the objects back up again so you can throw them down the hill once more. And this lifting will require (at least) the same amount of energy as you are able to get out of them by making them fall.

So conservation of energy holds, and this is sadly not a source of infinite energy.

Comment: good point, it makes sense, whatever goes down stays down. Also, i had a question, what if gravity was pulling equally on you on every side (assuming the gravity is about as strong as earth's) would the gravity cancel out? what would happen? would you be pulled apart? would yo ufeel a difference?

Comment: @House At the very center of the earth, there is sort of equal gravity in all directions because there is equal amounts of mass around you in all directions. Gravity on you will cancel out and you will "hover". I don't believe that would rip you apart - even if you had *earth's* gravity in all directions, which would then be two times normal gravity on your body, then I believe the human body has proven to withstand more (more than two G's). (The pressure on you at earth's center would crush you instead, though, but that's another story)

Answer (score 1):

The system you describe would not work because something has to prop the ball on the hill, using energy. Ideally a system of infinite energy would require no energy input. If it were that simple, someone would have done it long ago.

That said, Gravity itself does violate the law of conservation of energy. Unlike electromagnetic and kinetic, Gravity has no defined source or limitation. It is constantly present in the universe and is not a result of any reaction or emission.
It also has no proven force carrier (graviton).

The real violation is gravity's output being dependent only on mass and proximity of objects. 
The closer two objects are to each other, the stronger the force of gravity becomes. The energy between the objects is increased exclusive of any decrease in another energy form. A good example would be a person dropping a penny from a skyscraper.

As the penny falls, it increases in velocity but energy given to it does not physically come from anywhere. The kinetic energy that is given to the penny is not dependent on anything but its mass and distance to the earth (and every other object in the universe.)

This indeed violates the law of conservation of energy.

However, an "infinite" energy source still cannot exist because any system will naturally follow the path of least resistance. With Gravity, things fall inward and it takes energy to set them back up. Wind is a result of atmospheric temperature differences, electrical currents require energy to flow, etc. It is technically possible (though highly implausible) to make a *near* infinite system through manipulation of gravity- but infinity is the asymptote.

Answer (score 0):

Gravity and other field forces increase when the distance between objects decrease. When the distance decreases, the force increase. Hence the energy of the system also increases. This seems to violate the Law of Conservation of Energy. But to not let them, the field forces, do so, we consider Gravity and many other field forces to be negative. So, the sum of all positive and negative forces in a closed system, our cosmos, then exactly equals to zero. And thus, this concept of negative energy helps not violate the Law of Conservation of Energy.