# Energy Creation Using Water, Generators, and a Pump

Tags: energy, gravity, newtonian-gravity, water, power

So a friend and I are arguing over an infinite energy idea that he had about using gravity, that is an almost infinite source of energy. Water to use to push a generator by dropping and hitting the generator at maximum velocity. This would then put the water in a location that a pump would pick the water up from the rest location and place the water back at the top of the contraption to have it fall again.

[image]

I keep saying that there will be no gain of energy from the system because it will cost more energy to pull the water back to the top of the system. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Hi Ryan, welcome to PSE. Lots of users dislike clicking off site, is there any chance you could take a screenshot, rotate it as it is currently  90 degrees off, (think of smartphones used by many on this site) and include a cropped pic in your post. And you are wrong.... sorry, no could be about it :)  Thanks

Comment: @Countto10 Can do I did not notice the issue until clicked the link my b. Will fix

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct. If there was a substantial amount of energy that could be gained from this process, it would be used. That's why waterfalls are used instead of pumps lol

Comment: The thing is that if you can get the water back to the top with less energy being taken out of the system as said [link] (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/213150/using-gravity-for-infinite-energy)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the gravitational potential energy lost in falling appears as kinetic energy, and if that was all transferred into the pump and back into gravitational energy as the water was lifted to it's initial height, it would work. Problem is there are various inefficiencies that tap the energy away from the water, various frictions such as electrical resistance in the pump/generator, turbulence in the water, sound, the impeller wasn't oiled etc. These show up as heat in the surroundings.

Comment: The issue is that he is not convinced by the small issues that could add up. The concept should be able to turn the generator with the force needed to move it and to have a contently flowing water source. Also as it produces the same amount of energy after the small minor inefficiencies are calculated it should work as a type of  "infinite energy"

Comment: Hey Ryan, Well its those small  inefficiencies that make it not work. Yes, you will be able to lift some of the water back to where it came from, but not all of it. Why is your comment not on the public site?